# Remove the QItemDelegate from QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I have the custom item delegate set for one column for `QTableView`. In some cases I need to remove it (i.e. set default item delegate). But it seems that QT does not allow this. The old delegate is used even after setting the new one.
According to QT documentation for `QItemDelegate` all handling should be done in the same delegate, but this may bring to performance issues. Is there any way to remove/reset to default the item delegate for `QTableView`.

Comment: have you tried to call setItemDelegate with 0 as argument? or maybe store the default itemDelegate() and than set it again?
The docs state that by setting delegate the old one is not deleted..

Comment: Plus 1 for the Pink Floyd cover.

Comment: Yes, I've tried setting item delegate to 0; it has no effect, since the QTableView still using the old one. Also I've tried to delete delegate set before, it brings to crash (even using deleteLater() method)

Comment: I remember running into a problem like. Sadly, you could always try multiple  QTableView objects :(

Answer (score 3):

I tried it in PyQt5 (sorry, im not able to write C++). I could set the standard itemGelegate to the view and then set a custom itemDelegate to one column. By using the „clicked“-signal  i could replace the custom delegate by the standard itemDelegate for this column and vice versa.

[image: custom delegate for column 0]

[image: changed to standard delegate]

This is my code, perhaps it helps:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets

class MyDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self)
        self.AlignmentFlag = QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter
        self.abstand = 2

    def paint(self, painter, item, index):
        rahmen = item.rect.adjusted(self.abstand, self.abstand, -self.abstand, -self.abstand)  
        eintrag = index.data() 
        painter.save()
        painter.drawText(rahmen,self.AlignmentFlag, eintrag)
        painter.restore()

class MyModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel): 
    def __init__(self,):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self) 
        self.items = [['a0','a1','a2','a3','a4'],['b0','b1','b2','b3','b4'],['c0','c1','c2','c3','c4']]

    def columnCount(self,items):
        cc = len(self.items[0])
        return cc

    def rowCount(self,items):
        rc = len(self.items)
        return rc

    def data(self, index, role=2):
        return self.items[index.row()][index.column()]

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QTableView): 
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QTableView.__init__(self)
        self.setModel(MyModel())
        self.setGeometry(200,200,530,120)
        self.delegate_1 = MyDelegate()
        self.delegate_2 = QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate()
        self.setItemDelegate(self.delegate_2)
        self.setItemDelegateForColumn(0,self.delegate_1)        
        self.clicked.connect(self.changeDelegate)

    def changeDelegate(self,index):
        if index.column() == 0:
            delegate_new = self.delegate_2 if self.itemDelegateForColumn(index.column()) == self.delegate_1 else self.delegate_1
            self.setItemDelegateForColumn(index.column(),delegate_new)
        else:
            pass

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 
widget = MyWidget()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I can't use python. The only option is C++.

Comment: But perhaps you can find important differences between your and my code in use of methods or attributes and translate them to C++.